# toggle radio button in html bootstrap 3.4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here i am trying to toogle radio button
here it is i want answer like this

[image]

```
i tried for this like
<label class=" btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
   <input type="radio" :id="choice.id" >Answer {{choiceKey+1}} {{ choice.choice }}
</label>

but it get all color like this
```

[image]

Comment: Please add CSS for simple content and hover effect

Answer (score 0):

Edited. I think it's more what you're looking for.

---

Starting point, in the Bootstrap docs, see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio). For this approach you will need jQuery.

Also note that each radio button needs the same `name` attribute so they all work together; when you click one, the others turn off.

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  // remove the background color from all labels.
  $("label").removeClass("btn-primary");

  // add the background only to the parent-label of the clicked button.
  $(this).parent().addClass("btn-primary");
});
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid #204d74 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-block active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-block">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-block">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need JS for this, you can do it CSS-only with the adjacent sibling selector (`+`). Rough example below:

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + label {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="radio" name="something" id="radio_1">
<label for="radio_1" class="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Answer 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="something" id="radio_2" checked>
<label for="radio_2" class="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Answer 2</label>

<input type="radio" name="something" id="radio_3">
<label for="radio_3" class="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Answer 3</label>

<input type="radio" name="something" id="radio_4">
<label for="radio_4" class="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Answer 4</label>
```